# web3js is not executing contract functions

Tags: web3js, javascript, nodejs

I am trying to call the following simple function from `web3.js` but none of the function is being executed as I find no transaction entry in ganache.

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.11;

contract FirstContract {
    uint value;
    address sender; 
    
    function getValue() external view returns(uint) { 
        return value;
    }
    
    function setValue(uint _value) external {
        sender = msg.sender;
        value = _value;
    }
    
    function getMsgSender() external view returns(address) { 
        return sender;
    }
    
    
}
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Welcome to Meta Mask</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Welcome to Meta Mask</h2>
    <div id="status"></div>
    <div id="address"></div>
    <div id="balance"></div>
    <script src="/node_modules/web3/dist/web3.min.js"></script>
    <script>        
        if (typeof window.ethereum !== 'undefined') {
         document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = "Meta Mask is installed";
         //window.ethereum.enable(); //To enable site for Meta mask
    } else {
        document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = "Meta Mask is not installed";
    }
    </script>
    <script>
        walletAddress = null;
        //Connecting to Blockchain
        var web3 = new Web3(Web3.givenProvider || "HTTP://127.0.0.1:9545");        
        var balance = null
        var id = null;
        var contactAddress = '0xB16bEc01bfe4F13D5e85A2F75F51893D797Df1F7'
        var abi = '[{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"getValue","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"_value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"setValue","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"getMsgSender","outputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"}]'
        const abiJson = JSON.parse(abi);
        const init = async () => {
            var contactAddress = '0xB16bEc01bfe4F13D5e85A2F75F51893D797Df1F7'
            var abi = '[{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"getValue","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"_value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"setValue","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"getMsgSender","outputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"}]'
            const abiJson = JSON.parse(abi);

            ac = await web3.eth.getAccounts()
            walletAddress = ac[0]
            console.log(walletAddress)
            const contract = new web3.eth.Contract(
                abiJson,
                walletAddress
            )
            //await contract.methods.setValue(5).send({from:walletAddress})
            contract.methods.setValue(5).send({from:walletAddress}, (err, txHash) => {
                    console.log('TX is', txHash)
                    console.log('Err is', err)
            })
        }
   
        init() // Call the functions
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

It is not printing neither error not txHash value

*Update*:

I am using `truffle deploy` to deploy on Ganache. The contract was already deployed. No changes were made.

**Update 2**

[image]

**Update 3** - `truffle-config.js`

```
/**
 * Use this file to configure your truffle project. It's seeded with some
 * common settings for different networks and features like migrations,
 * compilation and testing. Uncomment the ones you need or modify
 * them to suit your project as necessary.
 *
 * More information about configuration can be found at:
 *
 * trufflesuite.com/docs/advanced/configuration
 *
 * To deploy via Infura you'll need a wallet provider (like @truffle/hdwallet-provider)
 * to sign your transactions before they're sent to a remote public node. Infura accounts
 * are available for free at: infura.io/register.
 *
 * You'll also need a mnemonic - the twelve word phrase the wallet uses to generate
 * public/private key pairs. If you're publishing your code to GitHub make sure you load this
 * phrase from a file you've .gitignored so it doesn't accidentally become public.
 *
 */

// const HDWalletProvider = require('@truffle/hdwallet-provider');
// const infuraKey = "fj4jll3k.....";
//
// const fs = require('fs');
// const mnemonic = fs.readFileSync(".secret").toString().trim();

module.exports = {
  /**
   * Networks define how you connect to your ethereum client and let you set the
   * defaults web3 uses to send transactions. If you don't specify one truffle
   * will spin up a development blockchain for you on port 9545 when you
   * run `develop` or `test`. You can ask a truffle command to use a specific
   * network from the command line, e.g
   *
   * $ truffle test --network <network-name>
   */

  networks: {
    // Useful for testing. The `development` name is special - truffle uses it by default
    // if it's defined here and no other network is specified at the command line.
    // You should run a client (like ganache-cli, geth or parity) in a separate terminal
    // tab if you use this network and you must also set the `host`, `port` and `network_id`
    // options below to some value.
    //
    // development: {
    //  host: "127.0.0.1",     // Localhost (default: none)
    //  port: 8545,            // Standard Ethereum port (default: none)
    //  network_id: "*",       // Any network (default: none)
    // },
    // Another network with more advanced options...
    // advanced: {
    // port: 8777,             // Custom port
    // network_id: 1342,       // Custom network
    // gas: 8500000,           // Gas sent with each transaction (default: ~6700000)
    // gasPrice: 20000000000,  // 20 gwei (in wei) (default: 100 gwei)
    // from: <address>,        // Account to send txs from (default: accounts[0])
    // websocket: true        // Enable EventEmitter interface for web3 (default: false)
    // },
    // Useful for deploying to a public network.
    // NB: It's important to wrap the provider as a function.
    // ropsten: {
    // provider: () => new HDWalletProvider(mnemonic, `https://ropsten.infura.io/v3/YOUR-PROJECT-ID`),
    // network_id: 3,       // Ropsten's id
    // gas: 5500000,        // Ropsten has a lower block limit than mainnet
    // confirmations: 2,    // # of confs to wait between deployments. (default: 0)
    // timeoutBlocks: 200,  // # of blocks before a deployment times out  (minimum/default: 50)
    // skipDryRun: true     // Skip dry run before migrations? (default: false for public nets )
    // },
    // Useful for private networks
    // private: {
    // provider: () => new HDWalletProvider(mnemonic, `https://network.io`),
    // network_id: 2111,   // This network is yours, in the cloud.
    // production: true    // Treats this network as if it was a public net. (default: false)
    // }
  },

  // Set default mocha options here, use special reporters etc.
  mocha: {
    // timeout: 100000
  },

  // Configure your compilers
  compilers: {
    solc: {
      // version: "0.5.1",    // Fetch exact version from solc-bin (default: truffle's version)
      // docker: true,        // Use "0.5.1" you've installed locally with docker (default: false)
      // settings: {          // See the solidity docs for advice about optimization and evmVersion
      //  optimizer: {
      //    enabled: false,
      //    runs: 200
      //  },
      //  evmVersion: "byzantium"
      // }
    }
  },

  // Truffle DB is currently disabled by default; to enable it, change enabled: false to enabled: true
  //
  // Note: if you migrated your contracts prior to enabling this field in your Truffle project and want
  // those previously migrated contracts available in the .db directory, you will need to run the following:
  // $ truffle migrate --reset --compile-all

  db: {
    enabled: false
  }
};
```

**Update 3**

It's weird. The `nodejs` version works fine. Is it due to different way to fetch `abi`?

```
const Web3 = require('web3')
const MyContract = require('./build/contracts/FirstContract.json')
console.log(typeof MyContract.abi)
const init = async () => {
    // const web3 = new Web3('http://127.0.0.1:9545')
    let web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://127.0.0.1:7545"));
    id = await web3.eth.net.getId() 
    const deployedNetwork = MyContract.networks[id]
    console.log(deployedNetwork.address)
    contract = new web3.eth.Contract(
        MyContract.abi,
        deployedNetwork.address
    );


    ac = await web3.eth.getAccounts()
    walletAddress = ac[0]

    let result = await contract.methods.getValue().call()
    //await contract.methods.setValue(12).send({from:walletAddress})
    result = await contract.methods.getValue().call()
    console.log(result)
}

init()
```

**Update 4** (`index.html`)

[image]

Comment: how are you deploying it?

Comment: @AvocadoChocolate I am using `truffle deploy` to deploy on Ganache. The contract was already deployed. No changes were made.

Comment: @AvocadoChocolate is there anyway to debug why function is not being called?

Comment: did you use truffle migrate to migrate to the local blockchain?

Comment: @AvocadoChocolate the contract exist in blockchain. The `console.log()` of `contract` prints all functions.

Comment: @AvocadoChocolate I added ss of Ganache

Comment: @AvocadoChocolate I just checked the contract by using `web3.py` and it worked perfectly. The issue is via web3.js

Comment: show me your truffle-config.js code

Comment: @AvocadoChocolate updated at the bottom of the question

Comment: @AvocadoChocolate the NodeJS versioned worked fine. I updated the code. Do not know why is it happening

Comment: @Volatil3 maybe you are writing the code the wrong way. your use of callbacks in the first example (index.html) is not found in the nodeJs version of the code. try using async/await or promises instead of callbacks.

Comment: @KakiMasterOfTime Where? I am already usnig an async `init` function here. The frontend does not accept `require` hence I am directly embedding js file and abi. Can you guide why am I wrong?

Comment: @KakiMasterOfTime checked the updated question. I added the changed `index.html` file. Not working either

Comment: Turned out `web3 = new Web3(Web3.givenProvider || 'http://localhost:7545');` was the culprit. it was always going to `Web3.givenProvider` which was not the one I intended to use. I changed it to to `web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:7545"));` and it worked!